# Can a function f be locally invertible while having a Jacobian with det = 0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inverse-function, jacobian, inverse-function-theorem

I have learnt the Inverse Function Theorem, which states that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is of class $C^1$, and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

then if $det(Jac_f(x_0)) \neq 0$ i.e. the Jacobian is invertible, $f$ admits local inverse $g$, and $Jac_g(f(x_0)) = (Jac_f(x_0))^{-1}$.

In an exercise though I was asked to check if the function $f(x,y) = (\cos x+\cos y, \sin x+\sin y)$:

**A.** Has local $C^1$ inverse in the points $(x, y)$ such that $x-y\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$. (I have checked that the Jacobian in those points is NOT invertible).

**B.** Has local inverse in the points $(x, y)$ such that $x-y\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

So my question is: is there a way to check if a function has local inverse without this function satisfying the hypothesis of the theorem?

Comment: short answer to the question of the title: no, it cannot be the case

Comment: How about $f(x)=x^3$? Or, if you want a 2-D exaple, $f(x,y) = (x^3,y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can happen even in case of $n=1$, for example take $f(x) = x^3$.
The inverse theorem makes a claim in the other direction, that is if the determinant of the Jacobian is not zero, then there is ... .

Comment: Ok, this is clear. But if Jac is not invertible what can I say about the invertibility of the function? Nothing at all (except somehow prove or disprove that it is bijective)?

Comment: Correct.  As the example points out, if the Jacobian is not invertible anything could potentially happen.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you were asked for an inverse function, or for a $C^1$ inverse function. If the former, you can check by working directly from the definition. Every neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ contains an $\epsilon$-ball around $(x_0,y_0)$. So show that $f$ is not in invertible in any ball around $(x_0,y_0)$.

If the latter, then no, a zero derivative means the inverse doesn’t have a finite derivative.

Comment: In order to show that $f$ does not have a local inverse do I have to check that taking any $ \epsilon$-ball centered at $(x_0, y_0)$, $f$ restricted to the ball cannot be bijective?

Comment: The first part is wrong. See other comments/answers.

Comment: You'd just solve $(\cos(x_1)+\cos(y_1),\sin(x_1)+\sin(y_1))=(\cos(x_2)+\cos(y_2),\sin(x_2)+\sin(y_2))$ in a ball around $(x_0,y_0)$. And apologies, in this example, you look at what your $(x_0,y_0)$ is to determine whether the function  is invertible or not.